# Building a data import system

Tags: sql-server, etl

I have been tasked with creating an ETL system to take inputs from any of our 100s of clients and import the data into our live databases.

I am planning on importing the data into tables using SSIS in the form that the clients have provided and then my plan was to create configuration tables to filter, transform and map the data into the system.  Once the data is in the import tables I plan on using tables storing all the configuration to generate dynamic SQL to then do the imports with detailed logging of time, whether a row was imported and if not why, changes to configuration, etc.

The main reasons for implementing this system are:

- Import processes will be self documenting through the configuration
  tables
- If there are issues with some of the data in the file we can hold
  the record but still process the rest of the data
- Changes to the import process can be logged and controlled
- Imports into the live system can be queued and processed in periods
  of availability.

My question is are we reinventing the wheel?  Is there already an existing product that meets all of these needs.

Comment: I don't think you are reinventing the wheel, however, each database is unique, so yes, (according to me), your idea sounds good. In my case, I had to develop a staging with table with logging, etc. After that a Stored Procedure would run, that imports the relevant data into the relevant tables accordingly. So go ahead, unless you require assistance with this?

Comment: Yes and no... you are reinventing the wheel, but only because you have to. I've had to reinvent that wheel many times. Each time I needed a different wheel. It's the nature of the beast. In order to do it efficiently, it should be tailored to the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far.  If you've worked on something like this before do you have anything to watch out for?  Any gotchas or things that forced you to redesign?

Comment: How will the data be used once it is stored? This should factor into how far you go with making a full-featured system. Will the data be stored as reference data for operational business management? Will the data feed into other business processes? Will the data be used for analytics? all of the above?

Comment: How reliable are the incoming data? Is there a standard established for the trade of data? Or will it be a wild west of data transmissions? (varying and volatile file formats/layouts/types)?

Comment: @jamie the data is being loaded into a CRM.  The main goal of this is to get the data into the CRM.  Unfortunately the incoming data is more on the wild west side of things.  Clients can change formats without notice and one of the goals is for our support team to be able to quickly modify the ETL to support these changes.  Many of our clients don't have strong technical teams or change control in place.